# Finding the shortest distance between an point and a parabola

Tags: calculus

I'm  finding  the shortest distance between a point and a parabola. The point in question is $(a,b)$, and the parabola that we are given is $y = Kx(x-P)$
where $K$ and $P$ are constant.

How would you approach the problem and find the shortest distance

Comment: Right back at you: how would *you* approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'd start and write down the distance between $(a,b)$ and a point on the parabola $(x,y(x))$, which would look something like: $$d(x) = \sqrt{(y(x)-b)^2+(x-a)^2}$$
Now you try to minimize that.

Comment: I think that will involve solving a cubic equation.

Comment: This leads to an intractable 3rd degree equation in $x$